# Inflate a tablerow with id's on every item

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout, tablerow, inflate

I have a major problem with an application im trying to developer atm. I have this view as you can see in the link below. How can I inflate this so I dont have to spam it 10 times in my xml file? 
I also want to have separate id's on the items in column area, exercise, set/km, reps/min and the button. There will also be onClickListeners on each of those columns on each item. 
And I will save all of these in a database/text file so I can put every back at its place when user opens this view again. 
How can I do this in a sample way and keep an overview on each of the items?
And I should mention that all these items is in a tablelayout and on there separate tablerows.

[Example Picture](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/examplezb.png/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own custom view for a row, in code, which handles the button clicks internally. Use these inside other views (possibly through code only).

Comment: What kind of id should I use to separate my items. For example: im going to use the same TextView number 10 times, but I cant use number.setId(i); and use a for-loop to set the id's. Are there some other method I can use to set ids?

Comment: You can go through this blog: http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2011/05/26/custom-composite-android-component/